# XPath for span and div

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, lxml

```
<div id="buyNewSection" class="rbbHeader dp-accordion-row">
<h5>
<div class="a-row">
    <div class="a-column a-span4 a-text-left a-nowrap">
        <span class="a-text-bold">Buy New</span>
    </div>
    <div class="a-column a-span8 a-text-right a-span-last">
        <div class="inlineBlock-display">
            <span class="a-letter-space"></span>
            <span class="a-size-medium a-color-price offer-price a-text-normal">$13.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</h5>
```

Pls help on how can we get extract the price $13 using XPATH?

Also if the div id is not present, then what will be the XPATH?

I am trying to scrape using python. Appreciate any help.

Comment: </div> mistakenly missing at end.

Comment: Share your current XPath

Comment: what about this `//span[contains(@class, 'offer-price')]`

Answer (score 2):

Using lxml for parsing:

```
from lxml import html

doc = html.fromstring(raw_html)
doc.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"offer-price")]')[0].text
```

this returns: '$13.00'

the xpath portion is simply looking for all the spans: `//span` and filter those for a certain class marker `[contains(@class,"offer-price")]`

Comment: Or maybe `//span[contains(concat(" ",@class," ")," offer-price ")]` so any other classes (like `offer-prices`) isn't accidentally matched.

Comment: True, if there were a span with this class it would result in a false positive match but this could be remedied by simply adding spaces around "offer-price" without any other complication. And btw: i doubt that any element with the class 'offer-prices' would also be a span and not a list or table.

Answer (score 1):

```xml
//span[@class = 'a-size-medium a-color-price offer-price a-text-normal']
```

Comment: Note that some class names might be added dynamically, so searching by complete class names set can return undesired output

Comment: well, the answer is actually based on these html codes that was provided, if there were three of the same codes for example, OP could use `(//span[@class = 'a-size-medium a-color-price offer-price a-text-normal'])[1]` if he wants to get the center or just use XPATH axes as an alternative.

Comment: I think what @Andersson is saying is that trying to check that the entire "class" attribute value matches might be fragile. What happens if the order of the classes change? Or a new class is added (or removed)?